# Machine learning: Binary classification of patient outcome (good/bad) with multiple measurements

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have 23 patients who all have chemicals 'C1' and 'C2' measured in N different places in the brain. Using this data I want to predict weather or not a patient will have a good or bad outcome. Using sklearn how do I design my machine learning algorithm (and/or which algorithm should I use) so that it makes a single prediction for each patient instead of making a prediction for each unique measurement of C1 and C2?

NB: I have used pythons sklearn libary to split the data in to test/train based on group ID's. I am using.

Comment: question is not clear and complete. Please discuss in detail

Comment: This sounds like a typical classification problem. I'd suggest you take a look at SVM. scikit-learn also have an SVM implementation

Comment: will you put add the 23 patient data so we can test if the data is linear or non linear

Answer (score 1):

I could write 3 pages of suggestions since your question is super general.

But in summary, you need a **classification** model that will predict the class/label of your subjects. This could be for example an SVC or LDA.

Toy example:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

[image]

Comment: is the data best suited for a linear or poly kernel? how did you determine fitness

Answer (score 0):

Answer would be lengthy but problem shouldn't be considered straight forward.

You basically need to use a binary classification algorithm, 
first of all just check for the **relevant features to be considered**, there might be N places out of 23 which are important, hence take some hypothesis based on your understanding and try to check that in data.

Taking **less features would reduce the variability** hence ,make your model more robust.

Once you have set of N features, you can **try plotting** into a reduced feature space, and check if there is any distinguish line/plane could be drawn. 
Check this: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-data-visualization-in-python-89a54c97fbed

Now, once you see your data in approximate space(2d/3d) now goahead choosing algorithm:

SVM (Linear/ RBF/ etc.) - Depends on whether data can be linearly separated or any curve function would be needed. See: https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-934a444fca47

Logistic Regression (If certain linear separation is possible)

Decision Tree

Random Forest

Hope it helps!!